# Clear NGINX cache using FTP

Tags: nginx, cache

I have an NGINX server set-up to handle caching for a website (running elsewhere).

Works like  a charm, however we want to administrators to have an option to flush the cache from their backoffice. I was thinking of handling this using FTP, by simply removing all the files from the cache directory.

I have set up the caching like this:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/my_site levels=1:2 keys_zone=MY_SITE:8m max_size=2048m inactive=720m;
```

However the files are stored with permissions 700. How can I tell NGINX to also give permissions to the group (770)? I would add the FTP user I created to that group then.

Any other suggestion to handle the flushing would be OK (I heave read [the thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx)). The backoffice is located on another location so I would have to use some remote technology.

Comment: What's problem with using ssh instead of ancient unsecure ftp?

Comment: Another option: create a 'flag file' using whatever remote method is conventient, and set up a cron job to check for this flag and do whatever you need to flush the cache.

Comment: @VBart: it doesn't matter, I could use ssh too, but the cache files would still need the right permissions. I'm not going to allow root access from some external backoffice.

Comment: You don't need full root access for certain action under `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub><s>Stealing</s> Explaining the ideas from [VBart](https://serverfault.com/users/120807/vbart) and  [sendmoreinfo](https://serverfault.com/users/22758/sendmoreinfo)</sub>

Please don't use insecure FTP, especially for doing an action on permission-sensitive directory. The alternative is:

1. Use SSH with normal user and give `sudo` permission to particular script who doing nginx-cache clearance. For example put this script in `/opt/clear-cache.sh`.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   rm -rf /path/to/nginx-cache
   ```

   For security, don't forget to run

   ```
   chown root:root h/opt/clear-cache.sh && chmod 700 /opt/clear-cache.sh
   ```

   Then run `visudo` to adding below line in `/etc/sudoers`

   ```
   backofficeuser ALL=(root)  /opt/clear-cache.sh
   ```
2. Use cron to run script that checks periodically the existence of `flag-file`. This special file can be created via <s>FTP</s> SSH (SFTP/SCP). When the `flag-file` exist then the script will clear the nginx-cache. The example script.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   FILE=/path/to/special/file

   if [ ! -f $FILE ]
   then
       rm $FILE
       rm -rf /path/to/nginx/cache/*
   fi
   ```

   Then add it to cron via `sudo crontab -e`

   ```
   * * * * * /path/to/myscript.sh
   ```